# R: Update columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns

In R I have a data.table of the following structure:

```
DT <- data.table(M=c(1,2,3,4,5), N=c(2,3,1,1,4), mu=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), sigma=c(10,10,10,10,10))
```

Here M is the simulation number, N the number of observations an mu and sigma are the parameters for the normal distribution. According to the number of observations I want to generate random numbers out of a normal distribution with corresponding parameters mu and sigma. For example have a look at the second row: generating 3 random normal distributed numbers with mu=10 and sigma=10 by

```
rnorm(3,10,10)
```

These random normal distributed numbers shall be written in DT. For this I add as many columns to DT concerning the maximum of N by

```
DT[, paste0("X.", seq(1, max(DT[, N]))):=NA]
```

So for simulation M=3 I want to update only columns X.1, X.2 and X.3 by three random normal distributed numbers with mu=10 and sigma=10. But how can I do that with look on a really big data.table?

I have tried to solve this problem by a for-loop over the columns using the set-function

```
for (j in 5:ncol(DT)) {
     X.random <- rnorm(n=DT[, N], mean=DT[, mu], sd=DT[, sigma])
     set(DT, j=j, value=X.random)
}
```

But in this way the "condition" N, the number of observations, is not considered, because all columns X.1:X.4 are updated. Further on sometimes I am not sure, if the parameters are taken per row. How can I do that?

**Edit:**
Without reading your answers I´ve updated the for-loop:

```
for (j in 5:ncol(DT)) {
    idx <- which(DT[, N]-(j-4) >= 0)
    X.random <- rnorm(n=DT[idx, N], mean=DT[idx, mu], sd=DT[idx, sigma])
    set(DT, i=idx, j=j, value=X.random)
}
```

Unfortunately the `set`-function doesn´t write random normal distributed numbers to corresponding columns X.1:X.4, only boolean values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dcast`:

```
dcast(
  DT[, .(id=1:N, val=rnorm(N, mu, sigma)), by=.(M, N, mu, sigma)], 
  M + mu + sigma ~ id, value.var="val"
)
```

Produces:

```
   M    mu sigma           1           2           3        4
1: 1     1    10   -5.779204   -3.060535          NA       NA
2: 2    10    10   13.070796   15.765328    12.30571       NA
3: 3   100    10   99.720755          NA          NA       NA
4: 4  1000    10  998.277712          NA          NA       NA
5: 5 10000    10 9999.507019 9997.459322 10010.48480 10003.36
```

Though really you should probably keep the data in long format (i.e. the first argument to `dcast` above as data in that format is typically much more amenable to analysis).

Comment: This works great.
But for
`DT <- data.table(M=c(1,2,3,4,5), N=c(2,3,0,1,4), mu=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), sigma=c(10,10,10,10,10))`
`dcast.data.table` produces a warning because of `N=0`for `M=3`.
How can this be avoided?

Comment: It seems to be just a warning without any effect on the results, so I just ignore this warning and set `DT[, `0`:=0].

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly new to the data table world but this code seems to work (although it throws an error). I loop through the rows rather than the columns and assign a column name within the loop.

```
DT <- data.table(M=c(1,2,3,4,5), N=c(2,3,1,1,4), mu=c(1,10,100,1000,10000), sigma=c(10,10,10,10,10))


for (i in 1:nrow(DT)){
    X.random <- rnorm(n=DT[i, N], mean=DT[i, mu], sd=DT[i, sigma])
    j=paste0("X.", seq(1, DT[i, N]))
    set(DT, i=i,j=j, value=X.random)

}

DT

   M N    mu sigma         X.1         X.2        X.3      X.4
1: 1 2     1    10   -2.286063   -2.286063         NA       NA
2: 2 3    10    10   13.843578   13.843578   13.84358       NA
3: 3 1   100    10   97.616599          NA         NA       NA
4: 4 1  1000    10 1014.386157          NA         NA       NA
5: 5 4 10000    10 9992.771152 9992.771152 9992.77115 9992.771
```

Comment: I think that column-wise operations in a data.table are much faster and more RAM-efficient than row-wise operations. That´s the reason why I´ve taken the desicion for a column-wise for-loop. 
But without the knowledge of your answer I´ve tried something similar, but still without success. Have a look at my edited question.